# Configuration failures resulting into Test skip in TestNG with no information in XMLs

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am experimenting with TestNG and it is working from eclipse. I created a test suite and trying to run it from command line.

Build fails with error saying

Final output during build says:

```
  [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] Suite
   [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
   [testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] 
   [testng] The tests failed.
```

testng-results.xml and index.html don't have any failures reported.

testng-failed.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Failed suite [Default suite]">
  <test name="Default test(failed)">
    <classes>
      <class name="ABC.test.integration.PersistUrlTests">
        <methods>
          <include name="springTestContextAfterTestClass"/>
          <include name="springTestContextBeforeTestClass"/>
          <include name="springTestContextPrepareTestInstance"/>
          <include name="springTestContextAfterTestMethod"/>
          <include name="checkTest"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- ABC.test.integration.PersistUrlTests -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test(failed) -->
</suite> <!-- Failed suite [Default suite] -->
```

Test looks as follows:

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:spring-configuration/mydb-integration-testing.xml" })
public class PersistUrlTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

        @Autowired
        protected MobiusDatabaseServiceClient mobiusDatabaseServiceClient;

        @Autowired
        UrlDAO urlDAO;

        @Autowired
        ScraperUrlDAO scraperUrlDAO;

        @BeforeClass
        public void init() throws Exception {

        }


        @Test
        public void checkTest() {
            GetActiveCategoriesResponse response = mobiusDatabaseServiceClient.newGetActiveCategoriesCall().call();
            System.out.println(response.getCategoryList());
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
}
```

Suite looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="ABC.mydatabase.test.integration.PersistUrlTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

But on the other hand, last updated time for this file is in past. I am not sure if it is getting updated or not.

I am not sure how to debug these XML files generated by testNG as they appear to be out of sync to each other.

Which file should exactly be looked at? And why are they not supporting to what "configuration" failed?

Comment: What does your code look like.  Seems one of your beforeXXX method is failing, since the log shows as configuration failures as failure.  Also, how does your suite xml look like?

Comment: @niharika_neo added these details. I just have single test and yes, it seems to be failing for beforeXXX but not sure how it works from eclipse.

Comment: Will you share exception details or log about failure? one of the possible reason is not finding `file:spring-configuration/mydb-integration-testing.xml` while running through command line but found while running from eclipse. In that case you need to set base dir while running from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign test listeners to your test?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Group D - Using variables" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
  <listeners>    
    <listener class-name="com.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
  </listeners>
```

The test listener is catching all the failures and skipped steps / tests.